# Access Denied When Attempting To Edit A File ProgramFiles

Tags: c#, file, uac

I am trying to edit a config file in the program files. These config files are used by Windows services. Here's the details:

- I can't change the location of the file to be edited
- UAC is OFF
- Just in case, the app.manifest has been edited so it runs as admin

Here's the code:

```
public void UpdateDNSNameInConfigFile(string v, ConfigFileOption cf)
    {
        string ConfigFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + @"\<redacted>\<redacted>";
        string ConfigFileContents = string.Empty;
        string DNSName = v.Replace("/ucf:", ""); //Remove the command line arg from the value

        switch (cf)
        {
            case ConfigFileOption.CobanSystem:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.<redacted>System";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_AVL:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.AVL";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_DB:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.DB";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_DVD:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.DVD";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_FileAgent:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.FileAgent";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_Log:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.Log";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_Streaming:
                ConfigFilePath = ConfigFilePath + @"\<redacted>.Agent.Streaming";
                break;
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_Listener:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_InCar:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case ConfigFileOption.Agent_Tape:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        ConfigFileContents = File.ReadAllText(ConfigFilePath);
        ConfigFileContents = ConfigFileContents.Replace("<redacted>", v);
        File.WriteAllText(ConfigFilePath, ConfigFileContents);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "The code fails", the code fails how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the filesystem permissions to get (write) access to that files. If your system is protected against external or unauthorisated access you could also allow that the user *everybody* can change the file (write permission).

Comment: I added myself, "everyone", and "anonymous logon" to the folder. None worked. The code fails at "ConfigFileContents = File.ReadAllText(ConfigFilePath);." But I can read the file with a streamreader just fine.

Comment: Did you try to grand all permissions?

Comment: @ernest If using an StreamReader works to read this file, why don't you use that instead?

Comment: @rekire Yes. They have full access.

Comment: @Rafael I'm playing around with it. I just used a StreamReader to test. I'm trying to figure out how to read the data and then edit a specific line.